# Java Couchbase how to update a JSON child?

Tags: java, json, couchbase

I'm using dropwizard with couchbase.

I want to update a document. The documents I am working with have a structure like this:

```
  {
    "animal": {
      "cat": {
        "name": "snowball",
        "color": "black",
        "age": "7"
      }
    }
  }
```

I just want to update lets say the age.

I can get the document from couchbase as a JSON like this:

```
JsonDocument docToUpdate = bucket.get(docId);
```

and then I try to update it like this:

```
docToUpdate.content().put("age", "10");
```

But that just adds it to the top level so I get this:

```
  {
    "animal": {
      "cat": {
        "name": "snowball",
        "color": "black",
        "age": "7"
      }
    }
    "age": "10"
  }
```

Is there an easy way to do this -- to access the child JSONs? In looking for a solution I discovered subdocs for couchbase. Is that the way to go or is there a simple solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the wrong node.
Try this.

```
docToUpdate.content().put("animal.cat.age", "10");
```

Update query should be

```
UPDATE bucket USE KEYS "docId" SET animal.cat.age=10
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of using couchbase, I found out 'mutateIn' is useful and accomplishes what I want:

https://blog.couchbase.com/subdocument-couchbase-java-sdk/

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/subdocument-operations.html